# Memory status on Console for iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-management

i'm searching for some stuff...

I want to print the free memory available before my app launches in the xcode console.

Is there any way to do it??

or any other way to knw how much memory is available for ur app before launching?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: becoz of the multitasking..

my app is getting crashed.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run / Run with Performance Tool / Activity Monitor should give you lots of info about memory usage.